# What is a memory-efficient method to spread then gather columns? (see example)

Tags: r, reshape, memory-efficient

I'm trying to rearrange my data for downstream processing. I found a way to accomplish what I want, but it is memory-intensive and I'm sure there is a more-efficient way.

Here is an example from the data:

```
   X.1 Label       X
81  81    21 367.138
82  82    21 384.295
83  83    21 159.496
84  84    21 269.927
85  85    22 364.118
86  86    22 154.475
87  87    22 265.861
```

I want to rearrange the data to create a table of X values for each separate object, as shown below:

```
    1       2       3       4
1 367.138 384.295 159.496 269.927
2 364.118 154.475 265.861      NA
```

I can do this just fine using `spread`, `apply`, and `ldply` functions shown below:

```
X <- apply(tidyr::spread(X, Label,X), 2, function(x) na.omit(x))
X<-X[-1]
X<-plyr::ldply(X, rbind)
X<-as.data.frame(X[-1])
```

Here's the problem, the `spread` function generates the following table as an intermediate step:

```
  X.1       1       2
1  81 367.138      NA
2  82 384.295      NA
3  83 159.496      NA
4  84 269.927      NA
5  85      NA 364.118
6  86      NA 154.475
7  87      NA 265.861
```

This is fine for small data sets, but for large data sets the table generated is huge and I'm running out of memory which produces the following error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.4 Gb

I'm sure there must be a more efficient way of doing this without generating that massive intermediate table. Any ideas?

Comment: imho this depends on what to do with the data (i.e. your algorithm)

Comment: are you sure you're using spread correctly

Comment: As to whether I'm using spread correctly, it depends on your definition of "correctly"...I'm able to produce the result I want. However, I doubt I'm using it efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using `data.table`

```
dcast(DT, rleid(Label) ~ rowid(Label), value.var = "X")
#   Label       1       2       3       4
#1:     1 367.138 384.295 159.496 269.927
#2:     2 364.118 154.475 265.861      NA
```

**data**

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(text = "   X.1 Label       X
  81    21 367.138
  82    21 384.295
  83    21 159.496
  84    21 269.927
  85    22 364.118
  86    22 154.475
  87    22 265.861")
```

Comment: Wow...I guess it pays to do things the right way. This is perfect and SOOOO much faster. Thanks!